# ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController): ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Everytime I click on the user name I get this error (The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController in this your_list.html.erb)

This is your_list.html.erb

```
<span class="pull-right text-center">
  <%= image_tag avatar_url(list.item.user), class: "img-circle 
             avatar-medium" %></br>
   <%= link_to user_path(list.item.user) do %>
                <%= list.item.user.fullname %>
   <% end %>
</span>
```

This is my user Controller

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def shown
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @items = @user.items
   end
 end
```

This Image of my command line when I click on the button

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right the typo it should `show` instead of `shown`

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @items = @user.items
end
```

Create `show` template to your `users` folder like `show.html.erb`

Comment: thank you but now I get this error UnknownFormat (UsersController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant.  @fool-dev

Comment: The full error message is == UsersController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.

Comment: rename your HTML file` your_list.html.erb`  to `show.html.erb`

Comment: It seems to miss `show` template, create or rename the file to `show.html.erb` inside the users folder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to recheck **routes.rb** for routes entry like

```
resources :users
```

and controller rename action name **shown** to **show** and render the respective **your_list.html.erb** file

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @items = @user.items
  render :template => 'products/your_list'
end
```